# Can't access USB connected to WDR3600 acting as an access point

Tags: networking, home-networking, file-sharing, usb-storage

I have two routers at home: the one that my ISP provided me with is a Huawei and doesn't have the option for USB sharing, so I connected my TP-Link WDR3600 to the Huawei and took all the necessary steps to share the USB connected to my TP-Link.

The problem is that I can't access my USB and I assume that this happens because my WDR3600 is not connected to the Internet directly but is acting as a wireless access point.

The connection is accomplished through LAN-to-LAN and the DHCP server is disabled on my TP-Link. My TP-Link says the WAN port is unplugged and there is no IP address under WAN settings. My Huawei is on 192.168.1.1 and the TP-Link is on 192.168.1.11.

What could I do in order to be able to access my USB device?

Comment: Access your USB device from where?  Within your LAN or from outside on the Internet?

Comment: I want access from my LAN to start with

Comment: You need to read the [documentation](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WDR3600#down).  Seems like only FTP access is available.

Comment: thanks for the advice. It seems that the TP link needs an ip address which it doesnt have due to it s acting like a switch. I will try some more searching on the web and see if i can fix it somehow

Answer (score 0):

use the same IP address which you use to login into your AP. Ex: 192.168.0.1

You can open `\\192.168.0.1` either on Run or in windows explorer